# Is it a tetrahedron, 5-cell, or something else?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coloring, discrete-geometry

I am trying to a find a closed form for a infinite dimensional sequence. When I plot the values using a case when I only have have 4 dimensions I get:
[image: Unknown Shape]

My gut is that the shape is a 4-simplex, but I am not sure if it could just be a tetrahedron that lies in 4D. Which one is it, or is it something else? The 3D part is a regular tetrahedron. Searching was not useful because it just showed the 'net' of a 5-cell.

I am open to suggestions on how to do such things by myself. I know that the infinite dimensional sequence fits tightly in a polytope and so I will have to learn some more things to characterize the sequence.  I have never tried to something outside of 3D since Calc III, but didn't really need visualization skills for that.

Comment: It’s hard (for me, at least) to tell from an image. Have you tried picking 5+ points and checking if they lie on the same 3-dimensional hyperplane? It won’t tell you everything you need to know, but it would expose, fairly quickly I think, whether the points are full-dimensional or not.

Comment: With the centroid is approximately {17.9816, 4.76959, 36.0207, 37.7304} based on the points in the set, and the 5 farthest points from the centroid I have are {2, 1, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 5, 3}, {2, 1, 6, 3}, {3, 1, 6, 4}. I am trying to think about it based on the picture though, not so much analytically.

Comment: Think about what a similar depiction of a tetrahedral shape would look like if it where projected into a plane. Points on the near side of the tetrahedron would all be red and would fill a triangle on the plane. Depending on the shape of the tetrahedron, points near the far corner would likely fall somewhere within this triangle, providing many blue points there. So at that location, you would see blue and red points intermingled. I see nothing similar in your graph, so I suspect a tetrahedron, not a 4-simplex.

Comment: Your 5 points lie in a 3D space: Labeling them $A,B,C,D,E$ in order, you have $A+ D = 2B$ and $B + E = C + D$, which means that the space spanned by these 5 points is (at most) 3 dimensional.